# Work Item Tree Hierarchy

Tags: mdx

I have a mdx  query to the TFS OLAP like this:

```
SELECT 
[Work Item Tree].[Work Item Tree Hierarchy].&[269]
ON ROWS,
{[Measures].[Work Item Count],
[Measures].[Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_OriginalEstimate],
 [Measures].[Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_RemainingWork]} ON COLUMNS
FROM
[Team System]
WHERE
([Work Item Link Type].[Link Name].&[Parent], [Work Item].[System_WorkItemType].&[Task])
```

It works pretty well, but I need as result of this query not only the measures value from the tree hierarchy, but as well for the connected work item. Something like this:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[OriginalEstimate] AS
(STRTOMEMBER("[Work Item].[System_Id].[" + [Work Item Tree].[Work Item Tree Hierarchy].Properties( "System_Id" )+"]"), [Measures].[Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_OriginalEstimate])

SELECT 
[Work Item Tree].[Work Item Tree Hierarchy].&[269]
ON ROWS,

{[Measures].[OriginalEstimate], [Measures].[Work Item Count],
 [Measures].[Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_OriginalEstimate],
 [Measures].[Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_RemainingWork]} ON COLUMNS
FROM
[Team System]
WHERE
([Work Item Link Type].[Link Name].&[Parent], [Work Item].[System_WorkItemType].&[Task])
```

But it won't work.

Can you this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give something more than "It won't work"? Do you get a particular error message, or are the numbers returned in the results not what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

[Work Item Tree].[Work Item Tree Hierarchy].**currentmember**.Properties( "System_Id" )

Comment: It would be more helpful if you were to describe or explain your code

Comment: My edit on this answer was rejected. Explanation - You would have to specify the member of which you want to see the property. The `CURRENTMEMBER` function is used to point at the member which is currently in scope.